# Delay iOS app termination due to low memory condition

Tags: c++, ios, memory

I'm developing a linguistic app that, occasionally, needs to allocate a large amount of memory for a certain period of time (normally under 30 seconds). Unfortunately, iOS sends low memory warnings and sometimes terminates the app (roughly 5% of the times). Of course I can't rely on chance so I have to fix it. I'm trying to optimize the algorithm (it's basically looking for spelling and sound similarities using Levenshtein distance) but I'm afraid that using the file system instead of the memory would make the processing too slow. Is there any way to respond to low memory warnings if I know that the memory will be released soon? Any other suggestions?

A few details:

1. the core processing is done in the background in an NSOperation
2. the algorithm is written in C++ for performance reasons, and it uses C++ strings and mallocs.
3. the same algorithm ported to Objective-C is 10x slower, even though I haven't investigated the reasons
4. the app is not leaking memory. After the long processing, all the memory is properly released
5. the app is iPad only

EDIT: the bulk of the storage is a C++ vector with about 200K English words. I have to compare these words with some potential candidates for both spelling and phonetic similarities. For each candidate I have to iterate through the whole list of words and calculate Levenshtein Distance. The distance is calculated using a similarity matrix which statically allocated in a function. I'm still puzzled at why I start with a vocabulary which is about 2 MB and end up with 70+ MBs of live bytes during the processing.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained, at least in general terms, what all this storage is for, it would help.

Comment: I think `mmap` isn't counted as used memory, you might try that to get around the limitation

Comment: The killing is done by the kernel, so there is probably not much you can do in this case. Read here: http://newosxbook.com/articles/MemoryPressure.html

Comment: I would guess that the "expansion" is due to C++ "garbage" that is not being immediately reclaimed.  Probably if you investigate how C++ does their storage management you'll learn a few tricks that would allow you to cut max storage requirements 4x or better.

Comment: Maybe you can abort the processing and deallocate the memory when a low memory event occurs?

Comment: Also, your app is given a warning before being killed, and if you respond to that by cutting storage somehow (eg, clearing caches) you may survive.

Comment: All good suggestions, thanks! Yes, I have to figure out why I end up with so much unexpected memory overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't get around the OS terminating your app if it takes up too much memory. The best you can do is free whatever isn't necessary when you get low memory warnings and hope not to get shot down. Remember that in iOS all the apps share the same physical memory, and there is no swap, so 70MB is a lot.
2. If you're not sure as to why your app is taking so much memory, one thing to try is using the Allocations instrument to profile it.